# Vanity IP addresses? WARNING: geeky content

Tags: ip-address

I did a quick search on Google and couldn't find anything regarding vanity IP addresses. I'm sure there is a market niche here. Wouldn't you dish some cash just to have a cool IP address? Anyone selling 2.2.2.2?

Comment: No, I'd keep my cash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.3.3.7** and 1.2.3.4 look really nice - [and you would get DDoS'ed](http://labs.ripe.net/content/pollution-18) as a free bonus.

Comment: 1.3.3.7 makes the perfect honey pot

Answer (score 3):

When IPv6 starts becoming popular these IPs may turn out to be very bad investments.

Google is likely paying quite a fee to Level3 for their 8.8.8.0/24 and 8.8.4.0/24 allocations, but then again, Google has cash to burn so they don't care about how bad an investment it is considering how cool it makes them look to geeks, such as you.

Comment: Actually in the case of DNS servers, it's incredibly useful to have such memorable IPs (how do you look them up without DNS?), so I don't think 8.8.8.8 is vanity at all.

Comment: good point. openDNS would love something like that.

Answer (score 3):

The only vanity IPv4 address I would want is 255.255.255.255, which I can't have (Oh to be the broadcast address and expose all the horrific brokenness in IP stacks around the world...).

IPv6 addresses... dead::beef would be nice, or something with as many repetitions of 0xC0FFEE as practical.

I still wouldn't **pay** for it though.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are providing something like a DNS service for public consumption where knowing the IP addresses is required I don't see any value.

Comment: whats the value of having a "CAT1" reg plate? Still it retails for around 100k in the UK.

Comment: @Iraklis people can see your number plate, if you like showing if it has some value, who see's you IP very often?

Comment: Vanity is subjective. Some might value his IP more than his reg plate. Dont think i'm supporting either side of the argument. I'm just pointing out that ones reality is not the same as the reality of another person.

Answer (score 1):

I'm more bitter about the vanity urls. I had a chance to buy my first name in 1994, and I thought to myself, "Eh, 40 bucks is a lot of money." By the college conversion of 40 bucks = 24 pack of crappy beer, it WAS a lot of money.

Now it's running $25,000 and is nothing but a goddamn squatter site, just like every other 4-letter combination. Oh the bitterness.

Comment: you should be bitter with the fact that you didnt buy IT stocks back then.

Comment: Eh. The stock boom was late enough that I DID get a piece of that; paid off my college debt at least.

Comment: I was a week late to register 'sucks.org' (.com and .net were already taken, but not that much earlier) ... that's the only domain I wish I hadn't missed out on.  (well, I tried to figure out how to register 'jelly' in the cayman islands, but that was more as a joke, so I could name a machine 'petroleum')

Answer (score 0):

After years of trying to remember the dynamic ranges that my ISPs used to allocate, I was somewhat surprised to find my new ISP in North East Thailand is allocating 1.1.x.x which is easy to remember :-)